# Fix Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$content

Tags: php

I am getting the below error on my Joomla website:
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t7KG.png)

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$content in /home/ipmmw/public_html/templates/ipmm/sppagebuilder/addons/slideshow_full/site.php on line 121

```
if ($slide_item->content) {
    $output .= '<p class="details ' . $slide_item->cotent_animation . '" ' . $content_data_attr . '>' . $slide_item->content . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: What is the question ? $slide_item has not "content" member.

Comment: You could get rid of the message with `if (isset($slide_item->content)) {`

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a class property exists like this:

```
if(isset($slide_item->content)) {
 $output .= '<p class="details '.$slide_item->cotent_animation.'" '.
            $content_data_attr.'>'.$slide_item->content.'</p>';
}
```

or

```
if(property_exists($slide_item,'content')) {
 $output .= '<p class="details '.$slide_item->cotent_animation.'" '.
            $content_data_attr.'>'.$slide_item->content.'</p>';
}
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php